# How to use Altera's floating point multiplier megafunction

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga, quartus

I want to do two floating point numbers with megafunction. I created megafunction fpalt_mult but I didnt continue, 
I didnt find enough examples about how to do.

```
entity multix is
port(
        x: in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);  
       y       : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
       clk      : in  std_logic;
       reset    : in  std_logic;
       overflow : out std_logic;
       result   : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end multix;

architecture carp of multix is

 COMPONENT multix_altfp_mult_pup
    PORT (
            aclr    : IN STD_LOGIC ;
            clk_en  : IN STD_LOGIC ;
            clk : IN STD_LOGIC ;
            y   : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0);
            overflow    : OUT STD_LOGIC ;
             x  : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0);
            result  : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 DOWNTO 0)
    );
    END COMPONENT;
begin


multix PORT MAP (
        aclr     => aclr_sig,
        clk_en   => clk_en_sig,
        clock    => clock_sig,
        dataa    => dataa_sig,
        datab    => datab_sig,
        overflow     => overflow_sig,
        result   => result_sig
    );

end architecture;
```

Comment: Try Google query `site:stackoverflow.com vhdl floating point numbers`

Comment: https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/ug/ug_altfp_mfug.pdf